# how to solve "wodim no such file or directory.cannot open scsi driver" in 12.04LTS

Tags: cd, burning, cd-drive, cd-image

I'm created a shell script to burn a cd, which was running successful in ubuntu terminal, but it not running if I call this script from php and also I found an error in log file like,

```
wodim: No such file or directory. 
Cannot open SCSI driver!
For possible targets try 'wodim --devices' or 'wodim -scanbus'.
For possible transport specifiers try 'wodim dev=help'.
For IDE/ATAPI devices configuration, see the file README.ATAPI.setup from
the wodim documentation.
TOC Type: 3 = CD-ROM XA mode 2
```

If I look `wodim --devices` in terminal

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  dev='/dev/sg1'  rwrw-- : 'TSSTcorp' 'CDDVDW SH-S202J'
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

-

if I look `wodim -scanbus` in terminal

```
scsibus4:
    4,0,0   400) 'TSSTcorp' 'CDDVDW SH-S202J ' 'SB01' Removable CD-ROM
    4,1,0   401) *
    4,2,0   402) *
    4,3,0   403) *
    4,4,0   404) *
    4,5,0   405) *
    4,6,0   406) *
    4,7,0   407) *
```

Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What wodim command exactly did you run when the error appeared ?

The fact that `wodim --devices` lists `/dev/sg1` is somewhat strange. I would expect
a sg address with kernels older than 2.6. On newer kernels the address should
be like `/dev/sr0`.

The most plausible difference between shell and PHP would be a lack of permissions
with PHP (other user id?). A burn program on Linux needs rw-permission to the
device file.